# How to run method on private field using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a resource class as

```
public class SecureResource {

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    // some more things here
}
```

I would like to tun run `request.getHeader('X-AUTH')` using java reflection?

**what I have tried?**

```
Field f = response.getResourceClass().getDeclaredField("request");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.get("X-AUTH");
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest field com.sn.bb.service.SecureResource.request to java.lang.String
```

What is that I am missing? How can I run `request.getHeader('X-AUTH')` on `f`?

Comment: I tried that and got `No such instance method: 'java.lang.reflect.Field.getHeader'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're current trying to *get the field* as if it were a field on an instance of `java.lang.String`. Presumably you already have an instance of `SecureResource`, so you'd want to call:

```
Field f = response.getResourceClass().getDeclaredField("request");
f.setAccessible(true);
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) f.get(resource);
String auth = request.getHeader("X-AUTH");
```

(Where `resource` is a reference to the relevant instance of `SecureResource`.)

That said, even when you've got it working I'd strongly discourage it if at all possible. Your code won't work in scenarios where there's a strict security manager, it will be brittle in the face of a change of implementation, and it generally suggests you're trying to do something for which the class wasn't designed.

Comment: Jon, I see `NullPointerException` when I do `HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) f.get(response.getResourceClass().newInstance());`

Comment: @daydreamer: Well why would you call `newInstance`? You need to have an instance of `SecureResource` to start with, in order to get at the field. Take a step back and try to work out exactly what you're trying to do - imagine if the field *wasn't* private - what would you do then?