# NullPointerException while trying to invoke method on private field using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

The original issue is described [How to run method on private field using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473845/how-to-run-method-on-private-field-using-reflection)

The class is

```
public class SecureResource {

    private HttpServletRequest request;
        public SecureResource() {}

    @Inject
    public SecureResource(@Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    // more things
}
```

Based on @Jon answer

> (Where resource is a reference to the relevant instance of
>   SecureResource.)

I did the following

```
Class cls = response.getResourceClass();
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
Field f = cls.getDeclaredField("request");
f.setAccessible(true);
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) f.get(obj);
String auth = request.getHeader("X-AUTH");
```

and I get `request` as `null`

and the `Field f` is not null

```
private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest com.sunrunhome.blackbird.service.SecureResource.request
```

Please let me know where I am making mistakes here?

Comment: Maybe it is null because you are creating a new instance?

Comment: Docs on [`Field.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)), just in case.

Comment: @DennisMeng It appears he is using it correctly?

Comment: @JoshM I just figured it wouldn't hurt to have the docs on that method handy.

Comment: @ruakh, updated my question, it is not null

Comment: How does the the `HttpServletRequest request` object get instantiated? If not in the zero-arg constructor (or inline on the declaration of request, but that's not what you've shown) then `field.get(obj)` will return null.  obj is a newly created instance of SecureResource.

Comment: @earcam, I updated the question, please see the class constructors

Comment: @Inject won't work see sedbastian redl's answer (it's not circumvention DI frameworks just aren't that aware), also you'd need Class.getDeclaredConstructors(cls).newInstance(request); if you want to pass in the request

Comment: Just a thought - do you have an **existing instance** that you want to extract request from?  If so, then pass the instance in to Field.get() not `f.get(obj);` as obj is a newInstance()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct as written, but who says that `request` isn't *supposed* to be `null`? Show us the default constructor of your resource class. (Note: if you're relying on some injection to happen, it won't. Injection frameworks only work when you don't circumvent them.)

Comment: When I debug, I do `request.getHeader("X-AUTH")` and get `4a4493a3ec6e2ea32d762e1d1ce7a67d:admin:1377644176944` as value, so it means request is not `null`, right?

Comment: On what request object? Where does that come from, and why do you expect the object returned from `newInstance()` to contain it?